# I am getting failed to make TCP connection to port 8080: connection refused

Tags: python-3.x, cloud-foundry

10:07:34.779: [APP/PROC/WEB.0]  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
10:08:34.562: [HEALTH.0] Failed to make TCP connection to port 8080: connection refused
10:08:34.562: [CELL.0] Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.

Though my code is working fine on local machine

```py
class Health (Resource):#this piecc of code is to perform the health check of the application so that it can run successfully without crashing on cf
      def get(self):
        return "UP"

api.add_resource(Health, '/health')

if __name__ == '__main__': #read about uses of main
    app.run(port = '8080')
```

Comment: Do you have anything else that may be occupying port 8080? what operating system are you using? Also you should use code blocks for your `if __name__ == '__main__'` (just surround it with backticks) (`)

Comment: Hi Alex thank you for your response, On my local machine, it is working fine, it is not working on cf,The os used is Linux.

Comment: So if i understand you correctly you have a server hosting on port 8080 and a different machine trying to connect to that? if this is the case make sure that the second machine is connecting to the ip address of the server and not the localhost address (127.0.0.1 wont work on another machine)

Comment: I believe I misunderstood you, everything runs on the same machine. It works locally not on a different platfrom

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? Something that someone can drop into cloud foundry or run on their machine to get the output that you are describing?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks a lot for your inputs i just modified  app.run(port = '8080') to  app.run(host=`0.0.0.0`, port = '8080') and it is now working. i was not sure if i can post the entire script here.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure you're listening on something other than 127.0.0.1/localhost. That is not externally accessible so health checks and external traffic won't be able to access your app if you are only listening on 127.0.0.1/localhost.

The easiest way is to listen on 0.0.0.0, which listens on all interfaces. You could  technically listen on a specific IP, but that's more work and it ends up doing the same thing.

In my Python Flask apps which I run on Cloud Foundry, I end up doing something like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5001)))
```

The second part is not technically necessary as `PORT` should always resolve to `8080`, but that could change in the future so reading the `PORT` env variable is a good idea.

Hope that helps!

Comment: connecting to 0.0.0.0 is the key.